# How to refresh AngularJS directive after certain action

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to "refresh" (generate new values) directive after a function is triggered. My current code looks like this:

```
class FicheController {
    constructor() {
        this.words = `[
            { "en" : "cup", "pl" : "kubek" },
            { "en" : "desk", "pl" : "biurko" },
            { "en" : "chair", "pl" : "krzesło" },
            { "en" : "board", "pl" : "tablica" },
            { "en" : "sky", "pl" : "niebo" }
        ]`;

        this.parsedWords = JSON.parse(this.words);
    }

    init(lang) {
        // set lang
        this.setCurrentLang(lang);

        let totalWords = this.getNoWords(),
            randomNumber = this.getRandomNumber(totalWords),
            translation = this.getCurrentTrans(),
            randomWord = this.getWords()[randomNumber][lang],
            currentTask = this.getWords()[randomNumber][translation];

        // set current word
        this.setCurrentWord(randomWord);

        // set current task
        this.setCurrentTask(currentTask);
    }

    reinit() {
        let lang = this.getCurrentLang();
        this.init(lang);
    }
...

app.directive('watchForWord', () => {
    return {
        controller: FicheController,
        link(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            element.on('keyup', () => {
                let currentVal = element[0].value,
                    currentTrans = ctrl.getCurrentTask(),
                    check = ctrl.diffWords(currentTrans, currentVal);

                if(check === true) {
                    element.addClass('text-success');
                    ctrl.reinit();
                } else {
                    element.removeClass('text-success');
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="container-small">
    <h2 data-random-fiche="en" class="text-huge text-primary align-center"></h2>
    <p class="align-center text-grey ">to po polsku</p>
    <div class="input full-width">
        <input type="text" class="text-center" data-watch-for-word>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, I try to run `reinit()` but it doesn't do what I need. What can I do?

You can see it on CodePen: http://codepen.io/tomekbuszewski/pen/MKyGBg

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes when you try to force Angular play according to the Jquery(pure javascript) rules. Angular does not know and does not care about the `on('whatever')` event, and it only cares about ng-change, ng-click etc. For Angular to update its values, it needs to understand when it should happen, which is (roughly speaking) at the end of the digest cycle. Add $scope.digest() after your ctrl.init() is done executing.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still a beginner with a lot of jQuery background. Anyway, adding `scope.$apply()` after `ctrl.init()` didn't help.

Comment: could you as well share the rendering part? (html)